# How can manual get ip address of a website throw Google DNS, OpenDNS... by send and receive packet

Tags: java, sockets, dns, ip, packet

I want write a small program to get IP Address of some websites by manual send and receive data packet from Google DNS, Open DNS.

How can help me.

I wrote this but not work properly.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    String str="stackoverflow.com";
    DatagramPacket dp=new DatagramPacket(str.getBytes(),str.length());
    DatagramSocket ds=new DatagramSocket();

    dp.setAddress(InetAddress.getByName("8.8.8.8"));
    dp.setPort(53);

    ds.send(dp);
    System.out.println("SENDED");

    byte[] receive=new byte[1024];
    dp.setData(receive);

    System.out.println("PREPARING FOR RECEIVE : ");
    ds.receive(dp);

    System.out.println(new String(receive));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to implement the DNS protocol -- a starting point could be https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035

Comment: If you're not familiar with the way DNS works, worth looking at Wikipedia as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Comment: I know that, but i don't know struct of data which sended to dns server. Can you help me

Comment: I'm not going to write the code for you if that's what you mean. I would start by looking at the dnsjava lib that @Thor has posted and you will quite likely find the structures needed in there.

Comment: Oh, Thanks so much. I never hope you will write code for me. I have not this idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to implement the DNS protocol, [dnsjava](http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava) may interest you.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS protocol is defined in [RFC 1034](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt).